# PHP Limit upload size validation

Tags: php

I want to ask about **PHP Limit upload size validation**
I have made the code to limit size upload, but thats still get error

My limit size is 500 Kb
when I upload file above 500Kb to 2Mb, the validation is working
but when my file size above 2Mb, the validation isnt working

here is my first code

```
$maxsize    = 500000;
if(($_FILES['myfile']['size'] >= $maxsize) || ($_FILES["myfile"]["size"] == 0)) {
                    $error = true;
                    array_push($error_cause, "<li>File size is over limit");
                }
```

and this is my second code

```
if ($myfile->getSize() > 500000) {
                    $error = true;
                    array_push($error_cause, "<li>File size is over limit");
                }
```

To make it clearer, i make a GIF about the problem
[Here](https://media.giphy.com/media/7JEWXbLtNJVSismkIc/giphy.gif)

Comment: what is `print_r($myfile->getSize());`?

Comment: What do you mean your validation is not working when the file is over 2MB? Do you get any other error?

Comment: Your code should work as it is. And the fact that it works above 500kb should be a **clear** pointer in that direction. If it fails above 2MB, it looks like a webserver / php configuration thing (max upload settings).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: I mean, My limit to upload is 500Kb (so I can not upload file up to 500Kb) and my code is working, when I upload file size 501Kb to 2Mb (the validation is working) but when I upload file above 2Mb, the validation was not working and it's processed it but the file was not stored, it should get error  message validation because my upload file above 500Kb

Comment: Do you get any other errors when you upload a file over 2MB?

Comment: no error, but the error message validation should show up because it is above 500Kb

Comment: I'm pretty sure you **are** getting an error, but you are not seeing it. Check your logs, at the very least.

Comment: @AnandG, no, that's not how it works. Answers should answer the problem, not be _clues_. And if the answers are not useful to the OP, they are completely in their right to vote however they want.

Comment: @yivi In that case the OP should explain why, and [downvotes should primarily be used](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) for "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."

Comment: @yivi No one has the right to downvote the answer if it relevant but not answering. If you saying has the right to downvote, then no one will write the answer. BTW, if someone is trying to help, OP should learn to appreciate not downvote

Comment: No, that's not how [voting works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s).

Comment: Voting is anonymous for a reason. No one is obliged to explain how they vote. Up vote? Someone found your post useful. Down vote? The opposite. **That's the end of it**. But suit yourselves and spend time trying to answer stuff like this.

Comment: this is my program
https://media.giphy.com/media/7JEWXbLtNJVSismkIc/giphy.gif

Comment: @yivi, Dude, you need to learn Basics. If someone scaps your efforts, you have right to ask. Now stop being **** and grow up!

Comment: The only one of these answers that will help you is the one from MatsLindh, who's basically copying the duplicate target. You are receiving an error, but you are not seeing because it is lost in the ajax response. **CHECK YOUR LOGS**. And check your PHP configuration. I'm out.

Comment: the PHP configuration is not wrong
I have checked it, just like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

and there's no error in ajax response because it's working above 500k to under 2mb size

Comment: Have you checked your logs?

Comment: @saintadjie What does `phpinfo(); exit();` at the top of your controller page say for the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` values?

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic 101: 5MB ===> 5 * 1024 * 1024 bytes

To keep code clear, I often define units as constants:

```
<?php
define('KB', 1024);
define('MB', 1048576);
define('GB', 1073741824);
define('TB', 1099511627776);
// Then you can simply do your condition like
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', 5*MB);
if (isset ( $_FILES['uploaded_file'] ) ) {
    $file_size = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];
    if (($file_size > 0.5*MB) && ($file_size < 2*MB)){      
        $message = 'File too large. File must be more than 500 KB and less than 2 MB.'; 
        echo $message; 
    }
```

Comment: Why would the units cause a problem when he's comparing a 2MB file to `500000`?

Comment: They wouldn't. This is just some copypasta that is not really relevant to the problem.

Comment: Just to keep thinks clearly, I defined the units, @saintadjie would like to specify the file size between 500KB and 2000KB, this is the desired code. it's true, I collected it from many places, but I adapted it to respond to the problem.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all. The OP can use your code, and will still have the same problem, since it's functionally identical.

Comment: I can read. No need to try it. Have you read the OPs code? Can you point in which way your code solves the OP problem?

Comment: Ok. I tried it. **It doesn't solve the OPs problem**. It´s identical. This is too silly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method:

```
$min =  500; //KB
$max = 2000; //KB

if($_FILES['myfile']['size'] < $min * 1024 || $_FILES['myfile']['size'] > $max * 1024){
 echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: this is also not working to me
For your information
My limit is 500Kb (so I can not upload file up to 500Kb)
and my code is working, when I upload file size 501Kb to 2Mb (the validation is working)
but when I upload file above 2Mb, the validation was not working and it's processed it but the file was not stored, it should get validation because my upload file above 500Kb

Comment: Haven't downvoted anything, but this doesn't solve the problem **at all**. The OP can use your code, and will still have the same problem, since it's functionally identical.

Answer (score -2):

The [value of `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` is 2MB by default](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize). Any file larger than this will be rejected by PHP.

You'll want to change the value in your `php.ini` file, and make sure to also [adjust the `post_max_size` setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size), as this is also considered for uploaded files.

When the uploaded file size is larger than the limit, the `$_FILES` array will be empty and you won't detect the upload at all (and thus, you won't show any errors).

You can [see the actual uploaded file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567861/detect-if-uploaded-file-is-too-large) by looking at the value fo `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']`.

Comment: What does your output from `phpinfo();` - without anything else called - show for those settings? Since file uploads are handled before code runs, changing the setting from `ini_set` won't do much.

Comment: @AnandG I cant devote it, my reputation is below 125, so It's not me

Comment: @saintadjie I figured it out who is the one. I have raised the flag from him/her. Sorry, I took your name. Deleting my comment